# upload file then zip and put it for download

Tags: php, upload, zip

I want let user upload their resume on the server,these file can be every suffix,then i will zip these file and put them for other users to download  by a link,is it safe enough???!!!
here is my code

```
$nameFile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$download_folder = "/download/";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$fileconpress = $download_folder.$nameFile.".zip";

$conpress = $zip->open($fileconpress, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
if ($conpress === true)
{
    $zip->addFile($tmpName);
    $zip->close();
    echo $fileconpress."<br/>";exit();
//return $name;
}
else echo " Oh No! Error";
```

and above code apparently does not work,please help me to have safe app,thanks

Comment: "above code apparently does not work" : could you be more precise ? ;)

Comment: for your server perhaps, but not for the users who download the files. A check for valid file-types should be done.Note: checking the suffix could not be enough, see [finfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

Comment: you know i want to upload some file then zip that file,above code just zip and when i want to unzip it,that file is not my own file,it is sth.tmp,ok???